# PHP 2 actions from a single Button

Tags: javascript, php, button

I am wondering how to get 2 actions in PHP from a single Button.
Attached here is an screenshot of the page:

[image]

I have the following code:
For the **Submit** button

```
<form method='POST'>
   <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="s_amount" style='width:20%;' required>
   <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
<?php
 $s_amount = $_POST['s_amount'];
 echo $s_amount;
?>
```

AND for the **Submit Code** button

```
    <button id="submitcode"type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit Code</button>
    <pre><code id="output">.../...</code></pre>
```

When the Submit code is pressed, this executes the following script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#submitcode").on("click", function(){
            ocpu.seturl("https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/base/R")
            //arguments
            var mysnippet = new ocpu.Snippet("V_CT="+$('[name="CT"]:radio:checked').val()+"\r V_TP="+$('[name="LENGTH"]:radio:checked').val()+$('#input2').val());
            //perform the request
            var req = ocpu.call("identity", {
                "x" : mysnippet
            }, function(session){
                session.getObject(function(data) {
                //data is the object returned by the R function
                $("#output").text(data);
            });
            });
        }) 
        });    
    </script>
```

What I would like to have is a single button, which not only gets the value next to the first submit button (here 12, see attached pciture) but also executes the script.

Many thanks !

Comment: Why not just put the whole lot in one single form in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

try giving id to form tag and on click on submitcode button call the form using its id.
for ex.

```html
<form method='POST'>
```

```js
function(session){
                session.getObject(function(data) {
                //data is the object returned by the R function
                $("#output").text(data);
                // using form id call the form
                $("#formdata").submit(); // it will simply submit the form.
            });
            });
```

```html
<form method="post" id="formdata"> <!--assign id to form tag--> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could finally do it very easily using js.

```
<input type="text" id="VTP" value="0">
```

and get the value in the javascript form

```
document.getElementById("VTP").value
```

@ nikhil borikar: Thanks but it did not work